# Prevent Adobe LiveCycle Designer from changing PDF Field Names

Tags: adobe, acrobat, livecycle

When I create a PDF text field in Adobe Acrobat forms and name it "DateOfBirth" I can use a PDF tool to programmatically find and populate that field by searching for it by name "DateOfBirth"

However, when I create the fields in LiveCycle Designer and I name a text field "DateOfBirth", it actually makes the field name "topmostSubform[0].Page6[0].DateOfBirth[0]".

Is there any way to prevent Adobe LiveCycle Designer from changing the original name that I give it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to Adobe support and they said there's no way to prevent or work around this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the field hasn't actually changed in this instance, what you are seeing is the full path of the field.  This usually occurs when you are calling the field from outside the subform where it is located and using the CTRL + click method.
Livecycle can be a little tempremental but you may be able to use the resolveNode event to identify it or if you're lucky data..DateOfBirth but that is dependent on where in the hierachy it is located.